# Distance from start point to end point in percentage in update

Tags: unity-game-engine, distance, transformation

```
float curpos = player.transform.position.magnitude;
float targetpos=GameObject.Find ("target").transform.position.magnitude;
float percentDist = (curCarpos / targetpos) * 100;
```

What I want to do is calculate percentage along the way from current point which is always moving to end point, starting from zero and once it reaches it should be 100.

For some reason it is starting from 14% decreasing to 0% and then starting from 0%-99%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it all wrong. Vectors magnitude in this case it is useless. You need something like this:

Call this before all movement.

```
float startDistance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, target.transform.position);
```

And this during movement.

```
float currentDistance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, target.transform.position);

float percentage =(currentDistance / startDistance) * 100f;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should get your starting position in order to get the percentage of the path traveled.

```
float percentDist = ((curCarpos - startingPos) / (targetpos - startingPos)) * 100;
```

Just when you start counting the percentage of the way traveled, get the float of your start position and do not update this variable after that at all.